# MySQL 8.0.26 Slow Query When Counting Results on Three Tables with Indexes

Tags: mysql

I have a statistics page on my internal admin site to show some traffic information on individual sites. However, the query is taking nearly 80 seconds to run, even with Indexes placed on the keys for each of the tables.

I'm typically running this query searching for session status within 7 days of the date ran.

```
SELECT
*, 
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(`session_id`) 
    FROM 
      `my-db`.`sessions` 
    WHERE 
      `my-db`.`sessions`.`site_id` = `my-db`.`sites`.`site_id` 
      AND `session_datetime` > '2021-10-17 00:00:00'
  ) as session_count, 
  (
    SELECT 
      `session_datetime` 
    FROM 
      `my-db`.`sessions` 
    WHERE 
      `my-db`.`sessions`.`site_id` = `my-db`.`sites`.`site_id` 
      AND `session_datetime` > '2021-10-17 00:00:00' 
    ORDER BY 
      `session_id` ASC 
    LIMIT 
      1
  ) as first_session, 
  (
    SELECT 
      `session_datetime` 
    FROM 
      `my-db`.`sessions` 
    WHERE 
      `my-db`.`sessions`.`site_id` = `my-db`.`sites`.`site_id` 
      AND `session_datetime` > '2021-10-17 00:00:00' 
    ORDER BY 
      `session_id` DESC 
    LIMIT 
      1
  ) as last_session, 
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(`site_profiles_id`) 
    FROM 
      `my-db`.`sites_profiles` 
    WHERE 
      `my-db`.`sites_profiles`.`site_id` = `my-db`.`sites`.`site_id` 
      AND `origin` = 1 
      AND `date_added` > '2021-10-17 00:00:00'
  ) as profiles_originated, 
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(`site_profiles_id`) 
    FROM 
      `my-db`.`sites_profiles` 
    WHERE 
      `my-db`.`sites_profiles`.`site_id` = `my-db`.`sites`.`site_id` 
      AND `scanned` = 1 
      AND `date_added` > '2021-10-17 00:00:00'
  ) as profiles_scanned, 
  (
    SELECT 
      COUNT(`site_profiles_id`) 
    FROM 
      `my-db`.`sites_profiles` 
    WHERE 
      `my-db`.`sites_profiles`.`site_id` = `my-db`.`sites`.`site_id` 
      AND `date_added` > '2021-10-17 00:00:00'
  ) as profiles_collected 
FROM 
  `my-db`.`sites` 
WHERE 
  `site_id` in (
    SELECT 
      DISTINCT(`site_id`) 
    FROM 
      `my-db`.`sessions` 
    WHERE 
      `session_datetime` > '2021-10-17 00:00:00'
  ) 
ORDER BY 
  `session_count` DESC 
LIMIT 
  25;
```

I'm trying to understand the results of EXPLAIN, but I believe the issue is because of the RANGE type of the index used on the datetime.

[image: Query EXPLAIN]

It's worth noting, I'm dynamically changing the ORDER BY clause depending on a sort dropdown selected by the admin user to sort the results by - site_id ASC/DESC, session_count ASC/DESC and profiles_collected ASC/DESC.

The performance of the profiles_collected DESC is significantly impacted when compared to the others.

**network_sites**

```
CREATE TABLE `sites` (
  `site_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `site_hash` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `site_address` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `site_status` int NOT NULL,
  `site_created` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `site_updated` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`site_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `site_id_UNIQUE` (`site_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `site_hash_UNIQUE` (`site_hash`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

**network_profiles_sessions**

```
CREATE TABLE `sessions` (
  `session_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `profile_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_hash` varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `session_ip_address` varchar(45) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `session_useragent` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `session_page_uri` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `session_datetime` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `session_has_data` tinyint DEFAULT '0',
  `session_processed` tinyint DEFAULT '0',
  `session_queued` tinyint DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`session_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `session_id_UNIQUE` (`session_id`),
  KEY `session_has_data` (`session_has_data`,`session_id`),
  KEY `session_processed` (`session_processed`,`session_id`),
  KEY `session_queued` (`session_queued`,`session_id`),
  KEY `session_datetime` (`session_datetime`,`session_id`),
  KEY `session_hash` (`session_hash`,`session_id`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`,`session_id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `session_page_uri` (`session_page_uri`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

**network_sites_profiles**

```
CREATE TABLE `sites_profiles` (
  `site_profiles_id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `profile_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `origin` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `scanned` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date_lastseen` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`site_profiles_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `site_users_id_UNIQUE` (`site_profiles_id`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`,`site_profiles_id`),
  KEY `date_added` (`date_added` DESC,`site_profiles_id`),
  KEY `origin` (`origin`,`site_profiles_id`),
  KEY `scanned` (`scanned`,`site_profiles_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Comment: What is MySQL version and post `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename;` results for all tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
PRIMARY KEY(a)
UNIQUE KEY(a)  -- redundant, DROP it
```

A PK is a UNIQUE key is an INDEX.

The last 3 subqueries can be combined:

```
SELECT  SUM(origin = 1)  AS profiles_originated,
        SUM(scanned = 1) AS profiles_scanned,
        COUNT(*)         AS profiles_collected
    FROM profiles
    WHERE date_added >= '2021-10-17'
```

And then `JOIN` to that.  However, there are some potential problems...

- How do `session.datetime` and `date_added` compare?  I'm assuming that a session is added before it happens?
- I assume you want to include midnight of the morning of Oct 17?

The first 3 subqueries can perhaps be similarly simplified.  Note that `MAX(session_datetime)` is sufficient for `last_session`.

Comment: Combining the subqueries made a massive improvement upon the query. Average load time is now 1.4 - 1.8 sec.

The session.datetime and the sites_profiles.date_added are completely separate and happen independently of each other, so filtering by each is important.

Midnight is not important. This was a static timestamp for the post. In Prod I'm checking seven days prior to the current time.

Comment: If 1.8s is not fast enough, start a new Question with the new query (plus tables); more improvements may be possible.

Comment: I'm working on a new question now. What is best practice for a new question title, since this is the next iteration of the query? Should I reference this question, and do we update this answer as the accepted answer and link to the next question?

Comment: @epool - Tag the new question with [mysql] and [performance] (or something like that.  Provide the query, `EXPLAIN SELECT` and the relevant table definitions.  Ask for improved performance.  Optionally reference this Question.